# springpython not installing in python 3.6.4

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install springpython in windows using PIP. I am already using python 3.6.4. But I am getting "`Spring Python only supports Python 2.6 and higher`".

where am I doing mistake?

[image]

Comment: Install `pip3` then try `pip3 install whatever`

Comment: why pip3 to install?

Answer (score 1):

As per https://github.com/springpython/springpython/issues/2 springpython is not supported on Python3. You may want to modify the source as per your requirement locally. Try using Python 2to3 converter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that springpython is written for python version 2.
That print is definitely won't work in python 3, would need parentheseses around the string.